# Build is not enabling in iTunes store, it disappears after processing

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, xcode8.2

I have built my application with deployment target 9.3 using Xcode 8.2.

Once I uploaded it to iTunes store it shows that "Uploaded Successfully" but the build disappears from iTunes after processing.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: This may not be your problem, but it takes some time (a few minutes, a few hours) before the build is ready on their end. You'll get an email stating it's there at that time.

Comment: Check in the activity tab, ther shows the progress of build...

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue many times.

Just check your email id which is attached with iTunes connect.
Your build has some issue and for that apple's developer team send email to you.

Fix that and upload new build.